# Secure, unique, encoded URLs/filenames in PHP?

Tags: php, url, encoding, proxy, security

I have a PHP website which acts as a web proxy/anonymizer, and I have it set up where each visited page is cached on my server for a limited time. To further secure things, I would like to encode the URLs into a set of hexadecimal characters, **but it needs be be unique enough to where no 2 URLs will ever clash together**; The cached page's file name will reflect the encoded URL, so I can't allow them to be overwritten by the visitation of another page.

Meanwhile, I've been using this:

```
$file = str_shuffle(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", urlencode($url))) .".html";
```

... But the problem here is that it's always random and not guaranteed to be fully unique. I'd like to make it so that users can bookmark their URLs (and revisit them within a given time period, without having to re-navigate to the page). How can I generate such a string?

Comment: 2 different urls won't clash even if you just do `urlencode` alone, why do you think they would clash?

Comment: UUIDs?  `/dev/urandom` + `base64_encode`?

Comment: What if the users are visiting a dynamic page e.g. dating-sites, where the messages are shown on post.php, and not are seperated for each user?

Comment: @Esailija yes, but urlencode on it's own is a high security risk, easily reversed by urldecode.

Comment: @Charles Thanks, that's much closer to what I'm going for. But again, base64_decode poses a threat here. I need an algorithm that can't be defeated so easily by an intruder.

Comment: @The87Boy Sorry, could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a "secure", as in *not reversible*, unique "encoding" of a URL, that's what [*hashes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) are for:

```
$hash = sha1('http://...');
```

The value will be unique for each URL, two identical URLs will hash to the same value, they're not reversible and are for most intents and purposes random values.

If you're talking about *encoding* (changing from one form to another) or *encrypting* (changing into another form using a *secret key*), then you're talking about reversible algorithms, in which case the result is unique by definition. *Encoding* the string won't be "secure", since there's no secret. *Encrypting* the string is as secure as you keep the secret.

So you have three choices:

1. encoding (e.g. `url_encode`, `base64_encode`), which is not secure and reversible
2. encryption (e.g. AES), which uses a secret and is secure and reversible
3. hashing (e.g. SHA1), which is not reversible and thereby secure

All three result in unique values (good hashes have a mathematically high enough probability to result in unique values).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Would `md5('http://...')` have the same "irreversible" effect? And which is more secure?

Comment: Yes, MD5 is a hash as described above. It's somewhat old by now and has somewhat higher probabilities of producing non-unique values and/or has other probabilities that make it possible to reverse to the original value. It's probably good enough for your intended purpose, but SHA1 or SHA256 (or even 512) is more recommended these days. The hashes are longer though, it depends on your priorities.

Comment: Well since my website isn't a government CIA operation, I suppose I could settle for MD5, lol. And it shouldn't be too hard to migrate the code to use sha1 in the future if I find the need to do so. Thank you!